# Android App not displaying images from cloud Firestore in release build but works in debug build

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, debugging, google-cloud-firestore

I recently finished building a wallpaper app. The app works fine in debug build, but not in release. I have added anonymous authentication to the app and the following rules in cloud Firestore:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Moreover I have added the release sha1 and sha256 keys to firebase and updated the json file as well.

Nothing seems to fix this issue.

The app displays the images properly here when I run it from Android Studio:
[image: The app displays the images properly here when I run it from android studio]

App doesn't work when I export it to Play Store and download. The images simply wont show up:
[image: App doesn't work when i export it to playstore and download, the images simply wont show up.]

Comment: Have you tried to test it on hardware, but uploading directly to the phone in developer mode?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about? Could you please explain in detail

Comment: Something like described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device

Comment: Yes I've tried that on my realme X it works completely fine on Android studio but I can't seem to figure out why these images won't load from playstore. I'm using glide to show images but if it works on the android studio version the relase version should work too right? Is this something related to firebase or authentication I'm so confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix it wasn't related to the keys at all disabling progaurd fixed my issue app works fine now looks like I need to create rules to let the app load images not sure but this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

when you upload an app in android studio the SHA1 key changes. There are two types of SHA1 keys one is used for debugging and other is used for Release. In your case when you use App in android studio it will not give you error as you have entered in firebase the SHA1 key for debugging.
for Android studio you need SHA1 key for Release for which you need to go to the play console and select your app. Then under setup go to app integrity here you will find SH1 key. Enter that key in your firebase authentication.

Always check your apk on emulator after the Signed built before uploading on PlayStore.
you can also find the SHA1 release key in android studio in Terminal.

you will need keytool command for that.

To execute Keytool command you need to go to the directory of Android Studio where Keytool.exe file is placed. for that you need to search Android studio directory. For me it was in "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin". So i entered in that directory using command

```
cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin
```

then use keytool command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\Yah\Google Drive\Android\booksapp\booksappkey.jks" -alias key0
```

This is the place where jks file is placed which was used for generation of signed apk
you will be asked for the password that you always used to generate signed apk

and the SHA1 key will be displayed which will be same as used in google play console.